# Create a query as a procedure in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am basically trying to do this MySQL script in BigQuery:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test` (IN tab_name CHAR(40) ) 
    BEGIN  
        SET @query = 
            CONCAT(
            'SELECT *
            FROM ', tab_name );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;  
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
END
```

In theory, this should let me run this script:

```
CALL test(`my_dataset.my_table`)
```

and it will perform my "`SELECT * FROM`" script on that table.

So far, this isn't working for me because BQ doesn't want to accept the quotation marks breaking across lines, so it says there is an "Unclosed string literal".

Any idea how I can accomplish this in BQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `mydataset.test`(tableName STRING)
BEGIN

DECLARE queryString STRING;

SET queryString = " SELECT * FROM mydataset."||tableName||"";

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString;

-- SELECT queryString;
END;
```

Execute the procedure:

```
CALL `mydataset.test`('mytable');
```

Comment: This works as long as my entire SELECT statement is in a single line. The actual SELECT statement I want to write is very long. Any idea how to get past that "unclosed string literal" issue when typing across multiple lines?

Comment: Within the double quotes, you can have a long /multi-line SELECT statements.